# OSX Terminal command to move all files in directory

Tags: macos, shell, terminal, command-line-interface

i'm at the OSX terminal now and try to move a lot of files from `~/Desktop/dir/` to `~/Desktop/dir/dir2`.

Command

```
mv *.* ~/Desktop/dir/dir2
```

doesn't work.

Comment: What error are you getting? From which directory are you running that `mv` command?

Comment: trying to mv from ~/Desktop/dir. Error is "too many argument"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're getting `"too many argument"` because there are probably too many files in `~/Desktop/dir/` that that are allowed by glob matching pattern on command line.

To move all files from `~/Desktop/dir/` to `~/Desktop/dir/dir2` use this `find` instead:

```
find ~/Desktop/dir/ -type f -execdir mv '{}' ~/Desktop/dir/dir2 \;
```

Or to move everything including files and directories use:

```
cd ~/Desktop/dir/
find . -path './dir2' -prune -o ! -name . -exec mv '{}' ./dir2 \;
```

i.e. other than `dir2` and `.` move everything to `~/Desktop/dir/dir2`

Comment: Where did you see that the OP had the "too many arguments" error?

Comment: @trojanfoe: That was in the response by OP to my question above.

Answer (score 0):

`*.*` matches all filenames that have a dot in the second or further position. It will not match filenames that do not have a dot. Using `*` instead will match all filenames that do not start with a dot.